# How to push back sidekiq job without retry in middleware?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

Is there a way how to push job back to queue from sidekiq server middleware? Or simply retry without counting it?

UDPATE: My background: I need to track status of the jobs in elasticsearch (one job follows after another one), but if elastic is not accessible, and I reschedule the same worker again, I would lose the chain (jid changes).

Comment: Do you think you could generate your own id (with SecureRandom for instance) and store this in elastic search instead of the sidekiq job id ?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like *the* idea. I will try to make it this way

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be for the job to re-schedule itself, then exit. For example:

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    if ready_to_perform?
      # Do stuff!
    else
      MyJob.perform_later(args)
    end
  end
end
```

Use with caution. You probably don't want a job to be stuck re-scheduling itself forever!

This isn't quite the same as "retrying without incrementing the retry counter" (which is a little more complicated to implement), but is sufficient for most use cases like this.

Comment: Thank you, it looks good, but it is not usable in my use case. Because I need to track status of the jobs in elasticsearch (followers), but if elastic is not accessible, and I reschedule the same worker again, I would lose the chain.

Comment: Could you please update your question with a little more detail on this requirement? How are you tracking the job's status? (And why do you need to track its status?) I'm not sure I follow what you're actually trying to achieve -- What is "the chain", and why would you "lose" it?

Comment: *Maybe* what you'd like to do is implement something like [this](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Core.html#method-i-deserialize), but decrement the `attempt_number` before failing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a working code but something like this could help you achieve want you want.

You could define a middleware and add it to sidekiq as below

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::RetryMonitoringMiddleware
  end
end
```

Now, you can define in the middleware as mentioned below:

```
class Sidekiq::RetryMonitoringMiddleware
  def call(worker, job_params, _queue)
    #calling the worker perform method to add it to the queue
    worker.perform(job_params['jid'], *job_params['args']) if should_retry?(job_params)
  rescue StandardError => e
    Rails.logger.error e
  ensure
    yield
  end

  private

  def should_retry?(job)
    # If worker is having a failure flag then only it should return a response
    # Need to check in which key we get a failure message
    (Integer(job['failure'])) == (1 || "true")
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you, it looks good, but it is not usable in my use case. Because I need to track status of the jobs in elasticsearch (followers), but if elastic is not accessible, and I reschedule the same worker again, I would lose the chain.